# Opening a TrueCrypt volume on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, truecrypt

How can I set up my Windows 7 laptop to open a TrueCrypt volume on startup?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Truecrypt FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq),

> Can I configure TrueCrypt to mount automatically whenever Windows starts a non-system TrueCrypt volume that uses the same password as my system partition/drive (i.e. my pre-boot authentication password)?
>
> Yes. To do so, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Mount the volume (to the drive letter to which you want it to be mounted every time).
> 2. Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main TrueCrypt window
>      and select 'Add to System Favorites'.
> 3. The System Favorites Organizer window should appear now.
>      In this window, enable the option 'Mount system favorite volumes when Windows starts' and click OK.
>
> For more information, see the chapter [System Favorite Volumes](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-favorites).

However,

> Note that, **unlike the regular (non-system) favorites, system favorite volumes use the pre-boot authentication password and, therefore, require your system partition/drive to be encrypted**.

So, Read from the **[Favourite Volumes](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/favorites)** section.

> Favorite volumes can be mounted in several ways:
>
> 1. To mount all favorite volumes, select `Favorites` > `Mount Favorite Volumes` or
> 2. press the '`Mount Favorite Volumes`' hot key (`Settings` > `Hot Keys`).
> 3. To mount only one of the favorite volumes, select it from the list contained in the `Favorites` menu.
>
> When you do so, you are asked for its password (and/or keyfiles) (unless it is cached) and if it is correct,
>   the volume is mounted. If it is already mounted, an Explorer window is opened for it.

Answer (score 1):

> Selected or all favorite volumes can be mounted automatically whenever
>   you log on to Windows. To set this up, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Mount the volume you want to have mounted automatically when you log on (mount it to the drive letter to which you want it to be
>      mounted every time).
> 2. Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main TrueCrypt window and select 'Add to Favorites'.
> 3. The Favorites Organizer window should appear now. In this window, enable the option 'Mount selected volume upon logon' and click OK.
>
> Then, when you log on to Windows, you will be asked for the volume
>   password (and/or keyfiles) and if it is correct, the volume will be
>   mounted.

Source: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=favorites